# Javascript don't work for loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm try to load the page content via the JQuery `load()` method. 
Here is the code

```js
$(window).ready(function() {
  $('#content').load('views/login.html');
});
```

```css
.mdl-layout {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mdl-layout__content {
  padding: 24px;
  flex: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-color--grey-100">
    <main class="mdl-layout__content" id="content">
    </main>
 </div>
```

(Sorry but i can't add the login.html to the snippet editor. It's a login form powerd by the mdl framework:/)

Now the Javascript functions for the form element from mdl does not work correctly. There are no errors in the developer console. I've also tried to reload all my javascript files after the load request by jquery?

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong with my script?

Comment: maybe the `<main></main>` tag causes this behaviour

Comment: I tried it. It's still the same problem....

Comment: are you sure there's nothing in console? please check `views/login.html` if it's the correct URL & inspect content of element `#content` if there's something inside. Also, check the `network` on chrome developer tools if there's a GET request to `views/login.html`

Comment: sorry my bad: change `$(window).ready(function() {` to `$(document).ready(function() {` - but my tests still fail using `document` instead of `window`

Comment: good notice @messerbill. change `window` -> `document`

Comment: @Theo html content is loading right, but the javascript stuff in the index does not work for this content,

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by myself. Here the solution:

I simply call the mdl javascript after the load method again.

```
$.getScript('https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-blue.min.css');
```

Now it works perfectly. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

if code you provided is copied from your .html file then structure is not good.
Here is working version:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8" />
       </head>
       <body>
           <style>
              .mdl-layout {
                  align-items: center;
                  justify-content: center;
               }

              .mdl-layout__content {
                  padding: 24px;
                  flex: none;
              }
           </style>
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-color--grey-100">
    <main class="mdl-layout__content" id="content">
    </main>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function() {
    $('#content').load('views/login.html');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS styles needs to be enclosed with  tags, and Javascript code must be closed within  tags
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry, but I've removed the html structure because I think it is not relevant for this question

Comment: Can you attach login.html?